# Is there a way to compile Objective-C in windows with eclipse without launching the MSYS terminal

Tags: objective-c, eclipse

I want to compile objective-c from eclipse with foundation.h support.

I can do it with GNUStep inside the MSYS shell, but I want to do it directly from eclipse Makefile without launching the Shell

is is possible?

As default XCode and a MAC machine is the right solution, But it will be great if atleast I can play with NSDictionary in a window machine before I really do in XCode

Comment: If that's already legal maybe use Hackintosh and have xCode installed there. This way, you can even run on the simulator or the device etc.

Comment: but that will kill the memory and CPU, yes I tried that before and it will definitely work anyway, but the question is .... eclipse in windows machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking the environment variables inside the GNUStep, I made the Objective-C code working directly with eclipse without launching the MSYS terminal

**Download and install GNUStep from http://www.gnustep.org/windows/installer.html**
**Download and install Eclipse Luna for C/C++ https://eclipse.org/downloads/**

After installation

You can launch GNUStep Shell and execute "set > paths.txt"

This paths.txt file will have all the related environment path with Unix directory structure

Convert all those paths to windows path structure and windows path delimiter ";"

You need to set few environment variables including GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, GNUSTEP_PATHLIST, GNUSTEP_SYSTEM_ROOT, GNUSTEP_USER_ROOT, GNUSTEP_HOST, GNUSTEP_HOST_CPU, GNUSTEP_HOST_OS, LIBRARY_COMBO, WD, GNUSTEP_IS_FLATTENED, GNUSTEP_FLATTENED..... with absolute path locations using front slash (avoid back slashes)

Make sure you provide the TMP and TEMP folder paths as shown below

[image: Eclipse->Window->Preferences>C/C++->Environment]

Create a C/C++ project in eclipse, You should name your makefile as GNUStepMakefile

As usual you can create the GNUMakefile with reference to GNUStep docs **http://www.gnustep.it/nicola/Tutorials/WritingMakefiles/**, introduce one extra target to execute the exe file

[image: GNUMakefile content]

Now you can write your .m file

You have to add the .m file to the eclipse file types and default editor as C/C++ editor

[image: Objective-C Code with Foundations.h]

Eclipse-Window-Show View->Other->Make->Make Target ........ introduce targets as **all, clean, run**

[image: Make targets run, all, clean]

Double click "all" from the Make Target

[image: Build Result for all make target]

Double click "run" from the Make Target

[image: Run Result run target]

Now you can compile and run Objective-C without launching the GNUStep Shell

**Note: you are only practising Objective-C with Foundation classes, you cannot create real IOS/MAC app here, for that you definitely need a MAC PC/Laptop**

If you don't want to use Makefile and directly use CDT to compile the code you can use this Technique **https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JQ8aIe4p6ds**